# Filter type undeclared?

Tags: c, macos, kernel-module, mach, kernel-extension

I should cast an `Interrupt Filter` to pass to a function, but the thing is, my Xcode always tells me that the `Filter` type is undeclared..

Here is part of my code:

```
interruptSrc = IOFilterInterruptEventSource::filterInterruptEventSource((OSObject*)this,
                                   (IOInterruptEventAction)&VoodooSDHC::interruptHandler,
                                   (Filter)&VoodooSDHC::interruptFilter,
                                   (IOService*)provider);
```

I'm new to `Mac` and `Xcode` so I don't really know what should I do in this case.

How does it complain about it being not defined, when the function is actually taking a parameter of that type?

Comment: Is this the *only* compile error? And is the header that declares `Filter` included in the current translation unit, before this line? OTOH you could forward declare it. BTW you are passing a pointer, is `Filter` a pointer type?

Comment: Compile with all warnings on, and post all compiler output you get.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the address of something and casting it to something that doesn't look like a pointer.  Either that's a pointer typedef (spawn of the devil) or that's not a good cast.

Are you sure it's not supposed to be:

```
(Filter *)&VoodooSDHC::interruptFilter,
```

?